# What is `SyntaxError.print_file_and_line` for?

Tags: python, cpython

In Python, `SyntaxError` objects have a `print_file_and_line` attribute:

```
>>> SyntaxError.print_file_and_line
<member 'print_file_and_line' of 'SyntaxError' objects>

>>> help(SyntaxError.print_file_and_line)
Help on member descriptor builtins.SyntaxError.print_file_and_line:

print_file_and_line
    exception print_file_and_line

>>> s = SyntaxError()
>>> s.print_file_and_line
# None
>>> s.print_file_and_line = [{'what am I for'}]

>>> s.print_file_and_line
[{'what am I for'}]
```

What is this for?

Comment: It presumably prints the filename and line number where the error was detected. Probably all exception classes are required to implement this method, either by inheritance or by overriding it.

Comment: It's not a `method`, but a `member` - so it's not callable, and is just a piece of data for something or other.

Comment: I suspect it's some kind of flag, but setting it to True doesn't seem to have any effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell, its presence is used as a marker to trigger some extra code in `print_exception` in `pythonrun.c` to print out the file and line of the syntax error, as well as the actual text of the line and a caret marking the position of the error, after printing out the rest of the stack trace. Remember, that the code with the syntax error is never executed - it failed to import after all - so it's not actually part of the stack trace. I get the impression `print_file_and_line` is more a piece of the implementation showing than something you can usefully interact with.

When you see the traceback printed from a syntax error, these lines marked with `<<<` below are printed due to that code.

```
$ echo ')' > syntax_error.py
$ python -c 'import syntax_error'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "syntax_error.py", line 1           <<<
    )                                      <<<
    ^                                      <<<
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

The code is in `pythonrun.c` here:

https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/37fcbb65d4589fbb5a72153e9338cf8e6495f64f/Python/pythonrun.c#L795-L827

And it looks like this:

```c
if (err == 0 &&
    _PyObject_HasAttrId(value, &PyId_print_file_and_line))
{
    PyObject *message, *filename, *text;
    int lineno, offset;
    if (!parse_syntax_error(value, &message, &filename,
                            &lineno, &offset, &text))
        PyErr_Clear();
    else {
        PyObject *line;

        Py_DECREF(value);
        value = message;

        line = PyUnicode_FromFormat("  File \"%S\", line %d\n",
                                      filename, lineno);
        Py_DECREF(filename);
        if (line != NULL) {
            PyFile_WriteObject(line, f, Py_PRINT_RAW);
            Py_DECREF(line);
        }

        if (text != NULL) {
            print_error_text(f, offset, text);
            Py_DECREF(text);
        }

        /* Can't be bothered to check all those
           PyFile_WriteString() calls */
        if (PyErr_Occurred())
            err = -1;
    }
}
```

---

I tried an experiment to test this. If I run this script:

```py
class FakeSyntaxException(Exception):
    print_file_and_line = None
    def __init__(self):
        self.text = 'Here is some text'
        self.lineno = 123
        self.offset = 6
        self.msg = 'Something went wrong'
        self.filename = 'example.txt'

raise FakeSyntaxException()
```

I see:

```
$ python3 python_syntax_test.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python_syntax_test.py", line 10, in <module>
    raise FakeSyntaxException()
  File "example.txt", line 123
    Here is some text
         ^
__main__.FakeSyntaxException: Something went wrong
```

Whereas if I comment out the line `print_file_and_line` I only see:

```
$ python3 python_syntax_test.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python_syntax_test.py", line 10, in <module>
    raise FakeSyntaxException()
__main__.FakeSyntaxException
```